# How do I delete a directory with hyphen in the name please?

Tags: directory, delete

Could someone help me delete a directory named `-ltr`
I accidentally created this when trying to list items.

None of this works:

```
rm -R *-ltr*
rm -R "-ltr"
rm -R '-ltr'
```

Comment: `rm -rf ./-ltr`, or `rm -rf -- -ltr`.

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
rm -r  -- -ltr
```

man rm:

To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
 one of these commands:

```
$ rm -- -foo

OR

$ rm ./-foo
```